# How do I adjust the format of data displayed in the CommCare report builder table

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to configure a report builder table to display non-numeric values for case properties. For every case property I add to the table, the only "format" I see displayed is sum, average, and count per choice. Is it possible to have the report builder table display non-numeric format data for case properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply display the case properties, you must create a list report, which is not aggregated.

If you are creating an aggregated report (data table type or worker report type), you must chose a way that the values will be aggregated. Since "sum" and "average" are undefined for strings (non-numeric data), you should choose count-per-choice, which will display one column per value, and a count of how many times that value appeared in the corresponding cell.

Suppose your cases looked like this:

```
+---------|----------|-------------+
| Patient | district | test_result |
+---------|----------|-------------+
| Joe     | North    | positive    |
| Bob     | North    | positive    |
| Fred    | South    | negative    |
+---------|----------|-------------+
```

If your report was aggregated by district, and you included test_result in your report with a "count per choice" format, then you would get a report that looks like this:

```
+----------|----------------------|----------------------+
| district | test_result-positive | test_result-negative |
+----------|----------------------|----------------------+
| North    | 2                    | 0                    |
| South    | 0                    | 1                    |
+----------|----------------------|----------------------+
```